# Debugging an access violation exception in a Java app

Tags: jvm, windbg, access-violation

I have the Britannica Ultimate Reference Suite 2015 installed on a 64 bit Windows 10 Enterprise machine. It used to work fine, but when I last tried to launch it, nothing happened. The Disk indicator LED flashed a little, but that was all. Inspection of the Event log revealed the following error:

```
Faulting application name: starter.exe, version: 1.0.0.1, time stamp: 0x442aec18
Faulting module name: jvm.dll, version: 5.0.220.3, time stamp: 0x4acf0d6a
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0008bcbd
Faulting process id: 0x1bb8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d8eedfa9234539
Faulting application path: D:\Program Files (x86)\Britannica 15.0\Ultimate Reference Suite\starter.exe
Faulting module path: D:\Program Files (x86)\Britannica 15.0\Ultimate Reference Suite\jre\bin\Client\jvm.dll
Report Id: a34d85a4-ca1d-452f-8b8f-0f183b9449d1
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

It appears that the JVM had thrown an access violation exception (0x00000005). When I loaded the executable in WinDbg (with my limited understanding of programming), the exception was thrown at the following instruction:

```
6d6cbcbd ff33         push    dword ptr [ebx]
```

This is in the stack window:

```
[0x0]   jvm!AsyncGetCallTrace + 0x21665   
[0x1]   jvm!AsyncGetCallTrace + 0x217b7   
[0x2]   starter + 0x17ed   
[0x3]   0x24994d0
```

I tried to reinstall it from the DVD, but now the installer behaves similarly. The Install Anywhere progress indicator quickly runs to the end and then nothing happens. It simply stops. I wasn't able to debug that. Attempts to remove the program from the control panel wizard similarly didn't get anywhere. It is listed without any size on disk in the add/remove list

It should be noted that all this started after I installed Anaconda, and I suspect it somehow messed up the JVM, although I don't want to commit a post hoc, ergo propter hoc.

How can I make Britannica run again?

Comment: There's clearly not much we can bring here; it's inside the jvm, for which there's no symbolic information (thus the stack trace is not very helpful in any way)... "ebx" points to an unmapped memory is pretty much the only thing that the dump is saying. I still find it kind of strange that Anaconda could have any sort of impact on the jvm... You could try to run the program in compatibility mode (right click executable > properties > Compatibility) and choose and older system version to see if that can help.

Comment: You might have a better chance on [superuser](https://superuser.com/) ; maybe someone with enough privilege could transfer your question there.

Comment: Even if you figure out what the cause of the problem is, you won't be able to fix it, because you don't have access to the source code and recompile it. Install it in a VM using an old OS and an old version of Java and no Internet access.

Comment: @Neitsa: you can close vote: community specific -> other site -> superuser

Comment: @Neitsa: Thanks for the explanation. I already tried the compatibility mode. No luck there either. I'll try on superuser.